# Extracting text from a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to analyze the NIST National Vulnerability Database using their JSON feed. URL is [here](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds#JSON_FEED). I am able to read the json file and can get it into a dataframe using pandas below.

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = '/nvdcve-1.0-2017.json/nvdcve-1.0-2017.json'

json_file = open(file_path, 'r') 

df = pd.read_json(json_file)

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(df["CVE_Items"])

#Select vendor data to extract the vendor name, product name
df2 = df[["cve.affects.vendor.vendor_data"]]
```

There are more rows that are returned but the first result is something like this

```
[{'vendor_name': 'microsoft', 'product': {'product_data': [{'product_name': 'windows_10', 'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '*'}]}}, 
{'product_name': 'windows_8.1', 'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '*'}]}}, {'product_name': 'windows_rt_8.1', 'version': [{'version_value': '*'}]}}, 
{'product_name': 'windows_server_2008', 'version': [{'version_value': '*'}, {'version_value': 'r2'}]}}, {'product_name': 'windows_vista', 'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '*'}]}}]
```

I am trying to extract only vendor_name and the product_name to place into new columns. I have tried to split the column using `df2["cve.affects.vendor.vendor_data"].str.split(' ', expand=True)` but when I do this nothing happens. Not even an error message. Any help is greatly appreciated.

-----Edit-----

When I look at the first 5 rows, this is what I get.

```
In: print(df.head(5).to_dict())

Out: {'cve.affects.vendor.vendor_data': {0: [{'vendor_name': 'microsoft', 'product': {'product_data': [{'product_name': 'windows_10', 'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '-'}, {'version_value': '1511'}, {'version_value': '1607'}]}}, {'product_name': 'windows_7', 'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '*'}]}}, {'product_name': 'windows_8.1', 'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '*'}]}}, {'product_name': 'windows_rt_8.1', 'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '*'}]}}, {'product_name': 'windows_server_2008', 'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '*'}, {'version_value': 'r2'}]}}, {'product_name': 'windows_server_2012', 'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '-'}, {'version_value': 'r2'}]}}, {'product_name': 'windows_vista', 'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '*'}]}}]}}], 1: [{'vendor_name': 'microsoft', 'product': {'product_data': [{'product_name': 'edge', 'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '*'}]}}]}}], 2: [{'vendor_name': 'microsoft', 'product': {'product_data': [{'product_name': 'sharepoint_enterprise_server', 'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '2016'}]}}, {'product_name': 'word', 'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '2016'}]}}]}}]}}
```

I don't get a table like I thought even though it says it's a dataframe. Is it possible there is something that is keeping some of the json structure?

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? It doesn't apply the change in place so your command basically creates a new variable.

Comment: It doesn't split the column. I could be wrong but I thought that '  ' will split the column on the space into multiple columns.

Comment: I am thinking I will need to create a lambda.

Comment: Instead of providing the `son` file, can you provide your `print(df.head(5).to_dict())` and a expected output?